# What is an easy way to browse samba shares on linux?

Tags: networking, mount, samba, browser, smb

I find it really frustrating when people send me links to samba shares while I'm on linux. I know some file browsers think they support copy/pasting smb links into the location bar but in practice it just doesn't work. Nautilus just says "Oops! Something went wrong". Dolphin correctly reformats the link and asks for a password but always fails with access denied.

The reliable way is to mount them: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99065/how-to-mount-a-windows-samba-windows-share-under-linux

But hontestly, I cbf rewriting all the `\` to `/` , creating a temporary mount point, entering the password, then opening a file browser at that location etc. People on windows can just click on the link and it opens. How can I get the same level of convenience on linux?

I'm running kubuntu but will happily take all suggestions.

Comment: ''man smbclient''

Answer (score 0):

If you open the "files" application, and click "other locations" at the bottom of the menu on the left, you will get a menu where you can enter a server address and connect to samba servers.

I use this feature to connect to my file servers at home.

Comment: Thanks! In "other locations" it has a "connect to server" box. There's a help button that says use "smb://..." to connect but no matter what I type in, the connect box is always greyed out for me. I have "Files 3.22.3".

Answer (score 0):

the server address should be something like smb://192.168.1.2/

if get the IP v4 address in the windows computer you can look in the Network & internet settings under the "properties"